# Why need @Query when I can write a method in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I just got started with Spring JPA and I am reviewing code written by my coworker. 
I see that he has been using the following code to find a Login object using username:

```
public interface LoginDao extends JpaRepository<Login, Long> {
        @Query("SELECT u FROM Login u WHERE LOWER(u.username) = LOWER(:username)")
        Login findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
}
```

Cant he just create a method like this:

```
@GET
@Path("{username}")
public Login getOne(@PathParam("username") String username) {
    Login login = loginDao.findOne(username);
    if (login == null) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
    } else {
        return login;
    }
}
```

What are the fundamental advantages of using @Query rather than writing a method approach. Or am I plain wrong and both have different purposes.

I personally dont want to write queries inside the code. I think mixing java with sql queries can make code look uglier.

Our stack is java, JPA, Jersey, JAX-RS, Postgreql, Spring Boot, Hibernate

Regards

Comment: The query does more then a simple `findOne` next to that in this case it wouldn't work as `findOne` requires an id not some arbitrary value.

Comment: I will update my question since you are right that findOne only takes id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, This is not an SQL query, this is a JPQL one. It would be a native SQL query if the `nativeQuery` attribute was set to `true`, which is not the case by default.

It is perfectly fine to create queries with JPQL, you will be able to switch from Hibernate to Eclipse Link or another JPA implementation without issues. You should also be able to switch from Postgres to MySQL, SQL Server...

You have to start to worry if your coworker creates queries with `@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "...")`, otherwise it looks fine to me.

Second, when you look to your repository declaration, you can see that the ID field for your `Login` entity is of type `Long`. That means the `loginDao.findOne(..)` method wants a `Long` parameter. Probably a surrogate key which is not `username`.

This is why your coworker created this new method: to find a `Login` row by something else than the `Long` surrogate key. (Here by username which is most likely a business key, but I do not know your application.)

---

Just for your information: Spring automatically creates queries with the signature of your repository methods (derived queries). For example:

```
public interface LoginDao extends JpaRepository<Login, Long> {
    Login findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Spring JPA will automatically create a query looking for a field named `username` and create a `WHERE` clause with it.

Notice that it is **not** the same than your coworker query because it will not use the `LOWER` function.

Some anchors in the JPA documentation about those derived queries:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords

---

Another thing about your title:

"Why need @Query when I can write a method in Spring JPA"

Well this `@Query` writes a method in Spring JPA. :^)

Comment: Really good answer. Now it is much clear to me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great, links shared ;)

Answer (score 1):

`JPARepository` has come up with some of the Supported keywords which will write the queries themselves based on your entity.

If we are looking something out of box from what JPARepository provides `@Query` is useful like - Joining multiple queries, writing native queries etc.

From your code snippet both would do the same

For more info you can refer - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html